# How to check class name in JavaScript or jQuery, and reload to another URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code.

```
<div class="1st-class"></div>
```

and I have a button, when I click it, the div will be like this.

```
<div class="1st-class goto"></div>
```

Now, how can I check the div if the class name has `goto`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the div an id :

```
<div id="target" class="1st-class goto"></div>
```

Then do:

```
if ($('#target').hasClass('goto')) {
    alert('Has class goto');
}
```

Note: You don't need to give the div an Id. You can use the `.1st-class` selector as well. However, giving it an Id makes it uniquely identifiable if you have multiple divs with the class `1st-class`.

References:

[`jQuery hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)